# Java Process on Windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, directory

I'm following an Operating Systems course in which the professor shows us some examples of process management in Java.
The examples are shown on Linux operating system and I am trying to modify the codes a bit in the few places that generate errors in WIndows.

The following code creates a process that lists files in a directory, and only serves to understand some mechanisms with which parents and children interact.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SimpleProcess1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
                                
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-la");
        System.out.println("Run command");
        Process process = pb.start(); 
         
        while (process.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println("The process is still runnning");
        }
        
        System.out.println("The process stopped. Any errors? " + (process.exitValue() == 0 ? "No" : "Yes"));

        String text = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

        System.out.println("Echo Output:\n" + text);
    }
}
```

I tried to modify the line of code that creates the "ls" process (which does not exist in windows)

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("dir");
```

but i get the following errors at run time:

```
C:\java\Processi>java SimpleProcess1
Run command
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
        at SimpleProcess1.main(SimpleProcess1.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:478)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:154)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
        ... 2 more
```

How should i modify the command?

Comment: There is no program 'dir' -- the 'dir' command is built-in to the command processor 'cmd.exe'.  You'll need to run cmd and pass it a command-string including the word 'dir'.

Comment: So it should be: ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "dir")
Right?

Comment: I changed it to: ProcessBuilder("cmd", "dir") 
This way the program is stuck on an infinite loop printing "The process is still runnning" but at least it start

Comment: ```new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "dir").inheritIO()```
* cmd - program to run
* /C - flag describing command that there will be a command
* dir - command itself
* inheritIO - to avoid infinite loop, so IO will be associated with your java process

Comment: It is working even without ".inheritIO()" thank you very mutch.
If you care about points and stuff just create an answer and i will mark the problem as solved!